# data still reads &quot; after httpuitility.htmldecode()

Tags: c#, asp.net, http

the data being read still has `&quot;` in it, even i put the `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode()` 
function how can i fix this? image below
[image: image of problem] 
and code shown below

```
string quer = "SELECT Date_Issued, quantity, Unit from Issuance_Consumables where Model = '"+ HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(model.ToUpper())+"' AND Branch = '"+ branch.ToUpper()+"' AND Dept = '"+ dept.ToUpper()+"' AND Company  = '"+company.ToUpper()+"' AND BU = '"+ bu.ToUpper()+"' AND Section = '"+section.ToUpper()+"'";

try
{
    connUs.Open();
    reads.CommandText = quer;
    readers = reads.ExecuteReader();
}
catch(System.Exception)
{
    //
}

while(readers.Read())
{
    dateissue = readers.GetDateTime(0).ToShortDateString();
    quantity = readers.GetDecimal(1).ToString();
    unit = readers.GetString(2);
}

gvModal.Rows[y].Cells[9].Text = dateissue;
gvModal.Rows[y].Cells[10].Text = quantity;
gvModal.Rows[y].Cells[11].Text = unit;
```

Comment: Not an answer for the question but consider using [parameterized queries](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Parameterized-Queries-ADO.Net.aspx) instead of string concatenation - to avoid sql injection cases

Comment: Empty `catch` clauses — always happy to see that nothing beats robust error handling.